# Отображение списка контактов в своем приложении из телефонной книги

Tags: android, контакты

Как отобразить список контактов в своем приложении. Например как это делает Telegram? 
Извлечь все контакты из телефонной книги, а потом запросы слать на сервер, и отображать тех кто зарегистрирован?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. При первом запуске если вы дали разрешение, он считывает все данные контактов и отсылает их на сервер, после сервер делает валидацию по разным признакам в том числе зареган ли пользователь. Для того чтоб показать список делается запросов относительно вашего аккаунта для получения списка контактов. Конечно не забывайте про кеширование, CRUD, изменение телефонной книги, генерации аватаров и всяких мелких подзадач.
По мне самый неприятный кусок это парс контактов из телефонной книги, если вам нужно не только имя контакта, например доп данные, email, thumnnail, number и тд придется погулять по разным content provider.